Issues with connection string during saving of data in .NET Core project
I am Mac user (old Mac, not M1). I have a .NET Core application, and I have Docker where I downloaded SQL Server image and I also have Azure Data Studio. In my Azure Data Studio, I can log in to my database with exactly the same details.
When I try to save data from my app I run into login issue. I have successfully added migrations and updated the database. I have tried to do it in several different ways, different password, different images, new docker, different versions of EF
This I have used to run docker
docker run -e "ACCEPT_EULA=1" -e "MSSQL_SA_PASSWORD=SimplePassword123" -e "MSSQL_PID=Developer" -p 1433:1433 -d --name=sql mcr.microsoft.com/azure-sql-edge

I am using Entity Framework Core 8
This is my connection string
builder
    .Services
    .AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(o => 
        o.UseSqlServer( "Server=localhost,1433;Database=LostPawsDb;User Id=sa;Password=SimplePassword123;TrustServerCertificate=True;"));

builder.Services.AddTransient<IPetRepository, PetRepository>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IPetService, PetService.Logic.PetService>();

This is because if I don't use it I get design exception
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace PetService.Database;

public class ApplicationDbContextFactory : IDesignTimeDbContextFactory<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext CreateDbContext(string[] args)
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ApplicationDbContext>();

        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer( "Server=localhost,1433;Database=LostPawsDb;User Id=sa;Password=SimplePassword123;TrustServerCertificate=True;");

        return new ApplicationDbContext(optionsBuilder.Options);
    }
}

using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using PetService.Database.Entities;

namespace PetService.Database;

public class ApplicationDbContext :  DbContext
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    { }

    public DbSet<PetEntity> Pet { get; set; }
    public DbSet<IllnessEntity> Illness { get; set; }
    public DbSet<PetMediaEntity> PetMedia { get; set; }
    
    public DbSet<LocationEntity> Location { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        if (modelBuilder == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(modelBuilder));
        }

        modelBuilder.Entity<PetEntity>().ToTable(nameof(Pet));
        modelBuilder.Entity<IllnessEntity>().ToTable(nameof(Illness));
        modelBuilder.Entity<PetMediaEntity>().ToTable(nameof(PetMedia));
        modelBuilder.Entity<LocationEntity>().ToTable(nameof(Location));
    }
}


"When I try to save data from my app I run into login issue" what exact exception do you get, and where? Side note, 1433 is the default port for SQL Server, you don't need to specify it in the connection string. "This is because if I don't use it" what is "it" here? What is it that you need to do to avoid an exception?

Is the app running in docker container too or it is running on local machine?

@GuruStron the app is running on local machine, yes

@gunr2171 is the same , the message doesnt change  Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided. [CLIENT: 192.168.65.1] and Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Connection[20004]
An error occurred using the connection to database 'LostPawsDb' on server 'localhost'.
